# is there a way to create custom Field / CancelField in flask wtforms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a simple wt-form class below. Along with the submit button, i need a cancel button to let users to back to the homepage. Is there a way to include this within the class ?

i tried to write a function and pass it to the SubmitField (labelled this as cancel), but it doesn't seem to work. here is my code:

P.s: I'am processing the form using wtf.quick_form(form), if that has any relevance to this problem

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(3, 16, message='3 to 6 Characters'), user_exists])
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), email_exists])
password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(5), EqualTo('confirm', message='Password Must Match')])
confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
# cancel = SubmitField('Cancel', validators=([go_back])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in the view. When the user presses the "Submit" button, `form.submit.data` is set to `True`. Likewise when "Cancel" is pressed, `form.cancel.data` is set to `True`.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate this:

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    # ...
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    cancel = SubmitField('Cancel')
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # The user pressed the "Submit" button
        if form.submit.data:
            # ...
        # The user pressed the "Cancel" button
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```